# AWS Lambda behind VPC times out when communicating with S3 even with endpoint

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda behind a VPC. When I try to get an S3 object, I get a "connect ETIMEDOUT" error. I set up an Endpoint and still have this problem.

I'm able to get the object if I remove the VPC so I know the VPC is the issue and not permissions.

I had already set up an Internet Gateway to communicate with the outside world (and I've confirmed that that works). Following Stack Overflow and these instructions(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/), I created an Endpoint to Service "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3" with "Full Access" and associated it with the Route Table I had created to get outside-world access.

[Screenshot of VPC Gateway Endpoint created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzyT.png)

The VPC, the lambda and the S3 are all in the same region. (Lambda and S3 are created via SAM.)

I initially had default AWS and S3 objects. I've tried setting the region for both with no luck.

```js
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1'});
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const s3FileParams = {
  Bucket: srcBucket,
  Key: srcKey,
};
const resp = await s3.getObject(s3FileParams).promise();
```

I also tried explicitly setting the s3 endpoint as `s3 = new AWS.S3({ endpoint: 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' });`

Let me know any other information I can provide and thanks in advance.

Comment: may be easier to use a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html). Debugging VPC connectivity is hard if you arent familiar w/ networking/security constraints currently inplace

Comment: I created a VPC endpoint [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSzyT.png). It's associated with the route tables of the subnets. Yet I'm still having the same problem.

(To clarify I just added that screenshot to the question.)

Do I need to do anything different in accessing the S3 if I'm using a VPC endpoint?

Comment: Routing table is attached to subnets and lambda is associated with vpc and subnets, the subnets you have chosen for lambda, do they all have the routing table with vpc endpoint route ? I hope ACL allows the traffic ?

Comment: All the subnets are associated with the routing table, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Requirements for using an S3 Gateway Endpoint:

- Ensure that the endpoint policy allows the appropriate access to S3. This is required in addition to the Lambda's IAM permissions.
- Add an entry to the route table(s) used by any subnets needing to use the gateway.
- Ensure that the Lambda's security group allows outgoing HTTPS traffic to either the internet (0.0.0.0/0) or to the prefix list ID (pl-xxxxxxx) for S3 in your region.
- You must enable DNS resolution in your VPC. Enable the `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` attributes on the VPC.
- The S3 buckets being accessed must be in the same region as the VPC.

Comment: Point-by-point:
- I granted Full Access in the endpoint policy. (Figured I can neaten it up once I get this working.
- The endpoint is linked to the proper route table and I see a reference to pl-xxxxxx (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3, 54.231.0.0/17, 52.216.0.0/15) with a Target of the VPC endpoint.
- Need to look at this but it connects to the outside Internet.
- Both are already enabled.
- Same region.

Regarding item 2, the route says `com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3` but the general entry point is https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. I don't know if that's an issue.

Comment: Just asking, is there a specific link that was your source for the above items?

Comment: I pulled this mostly from these two links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer was item 3 in Greg's list above. I switched to a new security group that (for now) allowed all traffic to anything in the outbound rules and that solved my problem.
(Now that I know there's a path forward, I can experiment with better outbound rules.)

Thanks to all! (And to the original folk who posted about VPC endpoints in other questions.)